# deployment to another server

Tags: ssis

How to deploy the SSIS package to another server ? What are the steps to be done for deployment in an another server ?

Comment: Belongs on superuser/serverfault ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use configurations (ours are in the datbase but it's simpler to start with file configurations.). I n the menu for SSIS choose configurations and set them up for dev and create a file. Test to amke sure the configurations work porperly. Then open the file and save a qa version after editing for the qa locations and a prod version after editing for the prod locations.

Then copy the config file to it's designated locatoin and the SSIS packa ge to it's designated location (again we use files for this not directly in SSMS although I think you can use SSMS if it is set up for this.)

THen schedule a job telling it to run the package.